# Calling s.tl() doesn't populate s.events

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics

We have just added [SuperTag](http://www.datalicious.com/what-is-supertag/) to a website and have observed one event is suddenly not populating the **s.events** value.

This code is executed on a button click.

```
var s = s_gi(s_account);
s.linkTrackVars = 'eVar39,prop39,prop45,eVar45,events';
s.linkTrackEvents = 'event49';
s.events = 'event49';
s.prop39 = s.eVar39 = 'mobile:NZ:specialists:call';
s.prop45 = s.eVar45 = 'john citizen';
s.tl(this, 'o', 'Button');
```

However when you inspect the request you can clearly see its missing the s.events property. (NOTE: I've blurred out live information to protect identities and origin)

[image: Missing s.events]

What could cause this issue?

Comment: I can't say that it's a solution, as it's been about 2 years since I've had to think SiteCatalyst, but for debugging purposes, try two things:

1) make sure you're only calling the `s = s_gi()` call once on the page for that account; once it's created, you shouldn't have to create it again

2) try passing in a custom object, rather than working with global state:
`s.tl(this, "o", "MyEventType", { linkTrackVars : "events", linkTrackEvents : "event6,event7", events: "event6,event7" });

See if that does you any favours or leads you in the right direction; it's hard to guess, without the code.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @Norguard unfortunately it didn't help me but was a good guess.

Comment: Hi @jennas, I am also working on AEM analytics, can you please tell me how got s_account name? actually, on page load, abcstage report suite got generated but I want to add some other eVars and events in the same report suite how can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've provided looks OK. I'd be willing to bet that somewhere in your `s_doPlugins` function, `s.linkTrackEvents` is being cleared (or `events` is being removed from `s.linkTrackVars` for whatever reason). At the end of your `s_doPlugins` block, add:

```
console.log(s.linkTrackVars, s.linkTrackEvents);
```

and see what that shows.

Comment: So you sir where correct with the plugins. I've never used SiteCatalyst before this is something that was just hand-balled to me. So according to the docs I can turn them off by `s.usePlugins=false`. However i have no bloody clue what side effects that might cause. So i implemented the following (also from the docs) but again unsure if its correct or not, however its resolved the missing s.events issue.

`
s.usePlugins=true;
function s_doPlugins(s) {
};
s.doPlugins=s_doPlugins;
`

Comment: Did you have a `s_doPlugins` previously? If not, you can safely do `s.usePlugins=false;`.. if you did (which I assume you did), then you may need to tweak your solution. Basically `s_doPlugins` gets called befor every request made to Adobe. A lot of the times code is placed in there to set defaults, copy variables, etc. You'd need to find where `s.linkTrackVars/s.linkTrackEvents` is getting overwritten at and tweak that logic. If you edit your answer with the s_doPlugins I can give a little guidance on it.

Comment: No we didn't have a s_doPlugins, i didn't even know it existed until you mentioned it. Its full of code that looks custom to me, its also unmanaged code from our application coming from `supertag-code-async-v11.js:9` which is on an external domain. I'm guessing the client has stuck this code into an adobe admin somewhere? I hope so because I've told them to change it or advise me to turn plugins off.

Comment: Adobe doesn't host it (except for use in their tag managers), but they do have a code generator that outputs code for hosting / downloading. Your client / client's analytics consultants should be able to help you out :)

Comment: Just heard back from the client, apparently its a feature in SuperTag, they can add their own javascript ugh. Their analytic's team just fix it. Thanks for your help :)